# Why some Mono spaced fonts not recognized by GVim?

Tags: vim, notepad++, fonts, gvim

I have a `cmtt10.ttf` font that I would like to use in GVim on Windows. This is TrueType font. And it is recognized by Notepad++. But when I try to use in GVim. It does not work.

Here is how I set in Gvim.

```
:set guifont=cmtt10
```

It gives `E596: Invalid font(s)` error.

Here is the link to the font. [CMTT10.ttf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/cmtt10.ttf)

Comment: As near as I can tell it's not a true monospaced font, or isn't flagged as one in the font metadata.